# Wordpress, filter pages in Admin edit screen

Tags: wordpress, posts

Is it possible to 'filter' which pages are shown in the 'edit' screen for pages ( http://cl.ly/6nLC ) in Wordpress? I have looked in the action / hook section of Wordpress for plugin developers but I could not find any.

What I am trying to accomplish is is that certain users can edit certain pages (and child pages) and other persons cannot edit those pages but might be able to edit other pages.

I have allready written a plugin which makes it possible to put different users in differtent groups, which now just needs to have different rights, which user is member of which group is stored in the user_meta table.

However if there is 'any' filter hook / method for this, can someone point this out, I think I will be able to go further from there.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a [`posts_where`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/posts_where) filter to add a condition to the SQL query to filter out some pages. A `load-{filename}` action can be used to ensure the filter is only applied when managing pages.

```
add_action('load-edit.php', 'my_load_edit_php_action');
function my_load_edit_php_action() {
  if ($_GET['post_type'] !== 'page') return;
  add_filter('posts_where', 'my_posts_where_filter');
}

function my_posts_where_filter($sql) {
  if (current_user_can('your_capability')) {
    global $wpdb;
    $sql = " AND $wpdb->posts.ID NOT IN (1,2,3)" . $sql;
  }
  return $sql;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, just what I needed, really couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Still quite helpful. I need to commit to memory load-[filename] action as that works great across admin and I appreciate this concise easy way to use it!